# internet explorer 7 iframe unloads when going back

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I'm implementing a browser history manager, just like rsh or yui browser history manager.

The idea was not to constantly poll the url hash of a hidden iframe, but to capture the
onscroll event of an iframe, when it scrolls to an anchor name on an urlhashchange.

So on every click i add an new anchor to iframe and set the iframe's hash to the anchors name. When pressing the back or forward button the frame scrolls to the previous or next anchor and the onscroll event is fired.

That works great on firefox 3.0+, IE6 and Opera but on IE7 when hiting the back button the
frame unloads and loses all its anchors.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening or have a fix for this "bug"?

BTW the onscroll idea comes from [this page](http://www.zachleat.com/web/2008/08/21/onhashchange-without-setinterval/).

Comment: Do you have any demo code we can look at?

Answer (score 1):

You might get some mileage from the DOJO toolkit which seems to have some workarounds for IE7
http://o.dojotoolkit.org/forum/dojo-core-dojo-0-9/dojo-core-development-discussion/dojo-hash-cross-browser-html5-onhashchange